# Profile a C Program - Time Shell Command

Tags: c, algorithm, shell

I have created two sorting algorithms, one of selection sort and of insertion sort. I am to do profiling of these sorting algorithms under various inputs, to draw conclusions as to their running time patterns.

How does one us the time shell command to do profiling of algorithm running times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on unix system, simply run your program using time

#  time  `<command>`

It should print something like this

real    0m0.181s      [ This is the total time taken ]

user    0m0.001s      [ Time spent in user mode ]

sys 0m0.002s      [ Time spent in kernel mode ]